# limits of a function 3

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know these are pretty basic but i could really use your help:

1. $\lim: \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\dfrac{1+x}{ 2+x}\right)^ {(1-\sqrt{x})/ (1-x)}$
2. $\lim: \lim\limits_{x\to 1}\left (\dfrac{1+x}{2+x}\right)^ {(1-\sqrt{x})/( 1-x)}$

For the first one, I add and subtract $1$ in order to get $e$. So i get:
$e^{-1} \lim: \lim_{x\to 0} {1\over 2+x} *{1-\sqrt{x}\over 1-x}$
With further rationing I got $-1/3$. But I don't think it's correct.

As for the second one, I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: For the first one, just plug in $x=0$ since you don't end up with an indeterminate form. For the second one, note that $1-x=(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the second limit, you can write
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1+x}{2+x}\right)^{(1-\sqrt{x})/(1-x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1+x}{2+x}\right)^{(1-\sqrt{x})/((1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x}))}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1+x}{2+x}\right)^{1/(1+\sqrt{x})}$$
and plug in $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first limit, you can just evaluate the function, as it is defined at 0. For the second one, you could rewrite the base with $e$ and find that the exponent goes to minus infinity.